# fix issue of UI of Framework with 2 storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have created Framework having 2 storyboard with applied condition

Its working fine if my project in which i import it have not using launch xib and size class with all devices,but if the project is based on size class and launch xib based, its not working properly, means the view inside my framework are cut a bit in case of iPhone 6 and above.

How to fix it, is i need to set size class for my framework as well? its have some complex structure so i used different storyboard.
Even just fixing auto layout on my framework storyboard not fixed the issue.

```
UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = nil ;

         CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
           if (screenBounds.size.height >= 568) {
          mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhone5" bundle : nil ] ;

          } else {
              mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhone4s" bundle : nil ] ;

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, set "Launch screen interface file base name" as "LaunchScreen" in info.plist.